# Derive a local state in React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I would like to derive a local state in my React app and use it in the same component.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'reactDOM'

function App(){
  const [origins, setorigins] = React.useState([1, 45, 7, 11]) // source of truth
  const [muted, setmuted] = React.useState([]) // derive from source
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
     evolve()
  }, [origins])
  
  // Transforms [23] => [{origin: 23, muted: 24}]
  const evolve = () => {
    setmuted(origins.map(o => ({origin: o, muted: o += 1})))
  }
  
  const addEntity = () => {
    // add random integer between 1 and 45
    const newEntity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45 ) + 1
    setorigins([...origins, newEntity])
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addEntity}>Add entity random</button>
      {muted.map(m => (
        <div className="entity">
          <p>Origin : {m.origin}</p>
          <p>Muted: {m.muted}</p>
        </div>
      )) }
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('reactz')
)
```

Can you improve this code above ?

Any performance issues I should be warned of ?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I was overthinking. The simpliest way IMO is to copy and transform the source of truth on the fly as described by Kent on his [blog](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-sync-state-derive-it).

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'reactDOM'

function App(){
  const [origins, setorigins] = React.useState([1, 45, 7, 11]) // source of truth
  const muted = evolve(origins) // derived state (useMemo ?)
  
  
  // Transforms [23] => [{origin: 23, muted: 24}]
  function evolve(data) {
    return data.map(o => ({origin: o, muted: o += 1}))
  }
  
  const addEntity = () => {
    // add random integer between 1 and 45
    const newEntity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45 ) + 1
    setorigins([...origins, newEntity])
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addEntity}>Add entity random</button>
      {muted.map(m => (
        <div className="entity">
          <p>Origin : {m.origin}</p>
          <p>Muted: {m.muted}</p>
        </div>
      )) }
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('reactz')
)
```

And for computational optimization, make use of useMemo hook.